# How to handle DenyConnection error raised by Django Channels in frontend

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

Is there a way I can deny a websocket connection in Django Channels and let the frontend know why the connection was refused.

The [channels documentation](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html) mention the `channels.exceptions.DenyConnection` error. When I raise it, I get a 1006 close event in the frontend, which is an *abnormal closure* and could be raised in other circumstances, I guess. I am looking for a way to indicate that the connection was refused.

Comment: Actually, I had another error in my code which caused the 1006 error in the front. When my code worked as intended, I received a 403 error in the frontend after raising DenyConnection.